# Spring batch/integration bean initialization error for remote directory in outbound adapter

Tags: spring, integration, batch-processing

I am trying to use spring batch/integration in the following way:

```
<bean id="ftpRemoteDirectory" class="java.lang.String" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="#{jobExecutionContext.get   ('batchProperties').getProperty('remote.directory')}"/>
</bean>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" 
    channel="sftpChannel"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" 
    remote-directory-expression="#{ ftpRemoteDirectory }"
    charset="UTF-8"
    use-temporary-file-name="false"/>
```

However I receive the following error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#13': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12] to required type [java.lang.String]: Failed to convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

The goal is to have remote-directory populated from the arguments passed into the JVM from spring batch admin.  That is why scope="step" is present on the ftpRemoteDirectory bean - so that we have access to the jobExecutionContext object.  So, i'm trying to get the property from the jobExecutionContext and then inject it into the remote-directory attribute of the outbound channel adapter.

I'd be open to suggestions for other ways to do this as well - I just can't get it to work.  Thanks!